SyntaxError: Unexpected token in JSON.parse - Invalid JSON format being sent in to the Backend
To give you some context:
I am trying to implement a simple Crud with a Client/Server architecture. While doing so I tried making a multi-step form, since a lot of the forms became quite long. But, I soon realized error checking while having a multistep form was harder than a simple one-page form.
In order to check if the Unique values of the form were indeed unused in the DB I created a react-query that will check it for me and display a message if the return message was false, meaning there is a duplicate in the DB.
As I was trying to implement said API endpoint I ran into a curious Error:
The value that is being send into the backend is a JSON string that contains values such as:
{"name": ""xValue""}
Which completely crashes my backend.
I could probably try to do some string manipulation to "clean up" the string before turning it into a JSON string and sending it back to the backend.
But I figured before I patch my error up I should probably address the real problem: the way I am capturing the value. I think...
These are some of the relevant code that I used for this "Unique Checking"
//useState that will hold the value:
  const [carnetValue, setCarnetValue] = useState('');

//React Query and onChange reaction function:
  const { data: isUnique } = useQuery(["checkCarnet", carnetValue], () => apiClient.checkCarnet(carnetValue), {
    enabled: !!carnetValue
  });


  const handleChange = (value: string) => {
    setCarnetValue(value);
  }

//The input itself:
  <input
          type="text"
          className="border border-blue-500 w-full py-1 px-2 font-normal"
          {...register("carnet", { required: "Este campo es necesario", onChange: e => handleChange(e.target.value) })}
        />

//The API Client:
export const checkCarnet = async (carnet: string): Promise<RevisarDato> => {
  console.log(carnet);
  const response = await fetch(`${BASE_API_URL}/api/auth/check-carnet`, {
    method: "POST",
    body: JSON.stringify(carnet),
    headers: {
      "Content-type": "application/json",
    },
  });
  if (!response.ok) {
    throw new Error("Something went wrong");
  }
  const returnData = await response.json();
  return returnData;
};

// In case necessary or relevant this is the Backend Endpoint
export const checkCarnet = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  const { carnet } = req.body;
  try {
    const yaExiste = await pool.query(
      "SELECT * FROM Personas WHERE carnet = $1",
      [carnet]
    );
    if (yaExiste.rows.length != 0) {
      return res.status(400).json({ result: false });
    }
    return res.status(200).json({ message: true });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    res.status(500).json({ result: "Internal Server Error 500" });
  }
};

This is an example of the displayed Error itself:
SyntaxError: Unexpected token '"', ""asdasda"" is not valid JSON
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)

Based on it I can only assume that It has something to do with the way The values are being captured. Maybe it's because I am using both a custom onChange as well as react-hook-form. Maybe some form of string manipulation is always necessary. I am not really sure.
Aside from the error that inspired this post I would also appreciate any feedback or input about the code itself or how to Error Check Uniqueness in Forms.
Edit: Full backend Error Message:
SyntaxError: Unexpected token '"', ""h"" is not valid JSON
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at createStrictSyntaxError (C:\Users\Administrador\Documents\GitHub\consultorioDentalv2\backend\node_modules\body-parser\lib\types\json.js:169:10)
    at parse (C:\Users\Administrador\Documents\GitHub\consultorioDentalv2\backend\node_modules\body-parser\lib\types\json.js:86:15)
    at C:\Users\Administrador\Documents\GitHub\consultorioDentalv2\backend\node_modules\body-parser\lib\read.js:128:18   
    at AsyncResource.runInAsyncScope (node:async_hooks:211:14)
    at invokeCallback (C:\Users\Administrador\Documents\GitHub\consultorioDentalv2\backend\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:238:16)
    at done (C:\Users\Administrador\Documents\GitHub\consultorioDentalv2\backend\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:227:7)   
    at IncomingMessage.onEnd (C:\Users\Administrador\Documents\GitHub\consultorioDentalv2\backend\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:287:7)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (node:events:520:28)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (node:domain:488:12)


{"name": ""xValue""} is NOT valid JSON - too many "

If you have double quotes inside your strings, you need to escape them. { "key": "\"asdasda\""}

The console.log just displays whatever I typed. Nothing weird on that side of things.
About the server side. I have most part of the CRUD working. Only this error checking breaks the backend.
Thats what I find weird. I can only assume its becouse of the onChange. That is the only thing I am doing different from all other API which rely on react-query alone. @C3roe

Can you post the actual data from the network monitor?

@jabaa You mean from the browser console? Or the backend console?

You can post both.

@jabaa added both pics for clarity

Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?) Please provide the data as text I've asked for the data, not the error messages. What is the data, that causes this problem?

@jabaa my bad I didn't know.

@jabaa Any string that I type into the input field gets me that error. Regardless of what I put into it. The frontend just give me the basic throw new Error when !response.ok The backend Error I will edit into the post

Please provide the data from network monitor. I've never heard that JSON.stringify(carnet) produces a string, that can't be parsed with JSON.parse. AFAIK, the result of JSON.stringify is always valid JSON. Can you please provide the body of the request, not the error messages?

@jabaa the content of the request is just "hello123". What is typed into the textbox.
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
X-Powered-By: Express
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'none'
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 1341
Date: Fri, 20 Sep 2024 08:36:15 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Keep-Alive: timeout=5

@jabaa This is all in the information that was within that request:
POST /api/auth/check-carnet HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:3000
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:131.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/131.0
Accept: /
Accept-Language: es-ES,es;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br, zstd
Referer: http://localhost:5173/
Content-type: application/json
Content-Length: 10
Origin: http://localhost:5173
Connection: keep-alive
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-site
Priority: u=4

Please provide a [mcve] of the backend. "hello123" is valid JSON and the body-parser should be able to parse it. You have to find out where the other quotes come from, before the body-parser parses the string. Do you use other middleware?

@jabaa Literally nothing! All relevant code was put into the post. No middlewares involved

If the actual request body only contains valid JSON "hello123" and the body-parser in your backend can't parse it because SyntaxError: Unexpected token '"', ""h"" is not valid JSON, something is really broken in your project or on your computer.

When sending data to the server, you are only sending a string:
body: JSON.stringify(carnet)

That's why you are getting a value with double quotes ""asdasda"".
Considering that on the server side you are retrieving the carnet key, you need to change the request to send a valid JSON:
body: JSON.stringify({ carnet: carnet })


What would be the value of carnet to produce the problem? If JSON.stringify(carnet) produces invalid ""asdasda"", why would JSON.stringify({ carnet: carnet }) not produce invalid { "carnet": ""asdasda""}?

@jabaa It did work with what he said! I just don't understand why... I have another Endpoints just like this one and they work fine its just this one thats... weird

json.stringgify(carnet)
was sending ""value"" resulting in extra double quotes in the payload
Wrapping carnet in an object  ({ carnet })  will ensure you're sending a valid JSON object.
